# Update column: multiply with a value based on another column's row divided by 2

Tags: sql

I need some help with an update statement as my SQL knowledge is limited.

**Table Example**

```
   MLv   | Prob1 | Prob2
------------------------
    1    |   0   | 0,080
    2    |   0   | 0,075
    3    |   0   | 0,060
    4    | 0,070 | 0,055
    5    | 0,060 | 0,040
```

For each row, I need to multiply the values of Prob1 & Prob2 with the value from MLv divided by 2. I want to do this without creating a new column to store that multiplier.

My code so far:

```
USE MyDatabase
DECLARE @MULTIPLIER INT
SET @MULTIPLIER = (SELECT MLv / 2.0 FROM _MyDatabaseTable)

UPDATE _MyDatabaseTable
SET Prob1 = COALESCE (Prob1 * @MULTIPLIER, Prob1)

UPDATE _MyDatabaseTable
SET Prob2 = COALESCE (Prob2 * @MULTIPLIER, Prob2)
```

That obviously doesn't work, because it doesn't know which MLv value to pick and that's where I'm stuck as I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use the column.  No variables are needed:

```
UPDATE _MyDatabaseTable
    SET Prob1 = COALESCE(Prob1 * MLV / 2.0, Prob1),
        Prob2 = COALESCE(Prob2 * MLV / 2.0, Prob2);
```

Only one update is necessary as well.

Comment: Oh haha, thanks. I have no idea why I was trying to make it more complex than it should be.

In the code you posted, you forgot to divide by 2 btw, but the idea is the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

**It Just A Single Line Qry, Try It As Shown As Below :**

```
UPDATE _MyDatabaseTable    SET Prob1 = COALESCE (ISNULL(Prob1,0) * (MLV / 2) , Prob1),Prob2 = COALESCE (ISNULL(Prob2,0) * (MLV / 2), Prob2);
```